# VBA Copy data to last empty row results in 2 rows of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data on one sheet that I am transposing to the last row of another sheet. Since I need to cherry pick which cell goes to where I cannot use a transpose function so I wrote the following macro:

```
Sub Copy_to_empty_row_test()
  
  Dim cs As Worksheet 'Worksheet to copy from
  Dim ps As Worksheet 'Worksheet to copy to
  Set ps = Worksheets("Test")
  Set cs = Worksheets("Imports")

        ps.Range("A258:C258").Copy
        ps.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

        'Date check
        cs.Range("B1").Copy
        ps.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'OT
        cs.Range("B4").Copy
        ps.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("I245").Copy
        ps.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


End Sub
```

The issue I am running in to is that my data will copy to 2 rows instead of one row. So I will get one row with the formula and then a new row with the data. I have tried changing the code around, with this being the latest iteration, but I still end up with 2 rows of data instead of one.

Can anyone help with what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `ps.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)=cs.Range("B1").value`.

Comment: @findwindow Didn't work. Seems the issue is with the pasting the formulas. When I paste the formula it goes down to the next row to paste the values. I tried pasting the formula last line in my code and I still end up with 2 lines instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Ranges

- The issue is that when you copy the first cells, you are also copying to column `A` where you are doing the `End(xlUp)`. So when doing it the second time the previous first available row in column `A` is occupied and the code copies the rest to the row below.
- I have assumed that you are copying all cells from the copy worksheet. If that's not the case, as in your code, you can easily replace `cws` with `pws` in the first copying lines.

```vb
Sub CopyToEmptyRowTest()

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').      
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the Copy worksheet ('cws').
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Imports")
    
    ' Reference the Paste worksheet ('pws').
    Dim pws As Worksheet: Set pws = wb.Worksheets("Test")

    ' Reference the first available cell ('pCell') in the Paste worksheet.
    Dim pCell As Range
    Set pCell = pws.Cells(pws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    ' Copy.

    cws.Range("A258:C258").Copy
    pCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

    'Date check
    cws.Range("B1").Copy
    pCell.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Alternatively, more efficient is copying values by assignment:
    'pCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = cws.Range("B1").Value
    
    'OT
    cws.Range("B4").Copy
    pCell.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Alternatively, more efficient is copying values by assignment:
    'pCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cws.Range("B4").Value

    cws.Range("I245").Copy
    pCell.Offset(0, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar!! First off, I appreciate you making my code more efficient and thanks for the detailed explanation. Secondly, this works!!! Thank you very much!